# How can I map a relationship with two options as a foreign key in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here are two models I have, should be self exlanatory.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Clan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clans';
}

class ClanMatch extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'clan_matches';
}
```

I need to create a function inside Clan model to fetch the matches. The way my database is currently set up there are two fields, home_clan_id and away_clan_id, it could be either.

How can I set up the relationship to check both? Here is how I would do it via eloquent.

```
$matches = ClanMatches::where('home_clan_id', $this->id)
->orWhere('away_clan_id', $this->id)->get();
```

Comment: As far as I know you can't define a relationship like that, you'd need to define two relationships and fetch both when you want to get all matches.

Comment: Are you willing to post an answer on how I can merge the two relationships? Home and away matches. I've tried the push method but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a Query Scope :)

```
public function scopeMatches($query)
{
    return $query->where('home_clan_id', $this->id)->orWhere('away_clan_id',$this->id);
}
```

Then you can call `Model::matches()->get()`.